# JComponent into non empty JPanale

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jcomponent

I'm going slightly mad.
I just want to insert a JComponet (containing a graphic) into a mainPanel that has to contain other objects before it. mainPanel is a simple JPanel, added to a JFrame, with two panels inside (one like a form panel with BoxLayout - JLabels + JTextField + JButton -  and one with GridLayout containing a set of JLabel to summarize some data).
When I click to submit button (on the first panel) I call a method that creates the JComponent objectComp (depending on inserted data), I set it visible, and I add it to mainPanel. It is not shown.
I also tried to:

- create another panel to contain JComponent, graphPanel, with BorderLayout, and add it to mainPanel.
- set explicit size to graphPanel and objectComp
- add objectComp directly to mainPanel and set it explicit size
- call repaint() to all panel/objects after adding them

Nothing works. I see the first two panel, but objectComp never appeares. The only working way is to add objectComp directly to JFrame, but in this way I loose all the other objects and I nedd to see them.

```
/**
 */
public class Draw extends JComponent {
// graphic
}

/**
 */
public class MainClass extends JFrame {
/**
 * main panel
 */
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
/**
 * graphic panel
 */
private JPanel graphPanel = new JPanel();

/**
 * 
 */
public MainClass() {
    super();
    // maximize
    setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    // create form panel and add it to mainPanel
    createFormPanel();
    // create summary panel  and add it to mainPanel
    createSummaryPanel();

    setContentPane(mainPanel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
}

/**
 * create JComponent
 */
private void createJComp() {

    draw = new Draw(data);
    draw.setVisible(true);
    graphPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    graphPanel.add(draw, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    graphPanel.setSize(500, 500);
    draw.setSize(500, 500);
    graphPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    mainPanel.add(graphPanel);
    graphPanel.setVisible(true);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            validate();
            draw.repaint();
            graphPanel.repaint();
            repaint();
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Which layout has your mainPanel?

Comment: *set explicit size to graphPanel and objectComp* - this NOT the way Swing works. You should NOT be setting a size. It is the job of each Swing component to determine its own preferred size and the layout manager will use that information to determine the actual size of the component. When doing custom painting you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your Draw component. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: @LittleSanti the default layout for `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`. Hence `new JPanel()` will return a `JPanel` whose layout manager is `FlowLayout`. Hence, according to code posted in question, `mainPanel` has `FlowLayout` layout. Does that answer your question?

Comment: so, which layout I have to set to mainPanel? thanks

Comment: I set mainPanel as BorderLayout. It solves my troubles. Thanks a lot to all, and sorry for my first stack overflow task mistakes!